# Finding the minimal variance

Tags: covariance, variance

I'm having some issues solving this question, hopefully someone can help out.

There are 10 girls and 5 boys in a classroom. Each of the 15 kids plays against the others exactly one time, where in each game there's only one winner. Each participant has a 0.5 probability to win. X is the total number of wins of the boys. What is the minimal value of Var(X)? (Note there may be a dependence between the games' results)

I tried finding the expected value which wasn't too difficult, since there's a total of 10 games the boys play among themselves, which guarantees 10 wins for the boys, and each of the boys plays against 10 girls - solving this is as easy as summing the expected values of 5 binomial distributions.

Finding E[X^2] wasn't as easy, so I tried using the formula for the sum of correlated variables, but I don't know the covariances of the Xi,Xjs.

Would love some help here. Thanks!

Comment: Your description of how you found the expected value sounds way too complicated. Every player has a $50\%$ chance to win each game, so by the [linearity of expectation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Linearity) the expected number of wins per player is $7$ (half their total number of games, $14$).

Comment: If the matches are independent, then the variances of the sum are the sum of the variances

Comment: @joriki that's exactly what I did, I just said I separated it into boys vs boys (which is a constant 10) and boys vs girls, and then applied linearity.

Comment: @Henry The matches may be dependent

Answer (score 0):

The minimal variance is zero. Place the children in a circle. Flip a coin. If it shows heads, everyone beats all players to their right. If it shows tails, everyone beats all players to their left. Thus, every game has a $50\%$ chance of going either way, and all participants are certain to win exactly $7$ games.

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. Can you elaborate how does this show the variance is zero?

Comment: @Guy The variance measures to what extent the number of wins varies about the mean. The mean is $7$. If the number of wins is always exactly $7$, there is no variance; the variance is $0$. More formally, the sum over the squared differences from the mean is zero, because the differences are all zero. Of course there's always the possibility that I misunderstood the question, though.